# Cannot leave Full Screen on TinyMce Wordpress (View->FullScreen)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

There's a bug in Wordpress which has affected all our Wordpress sites (Assumed to be a global issue?) where you cannot leave the Wordpress Fullscreen area in TinyMce because the dropdown menus do not show.

[image]

This has only been a recent issue as far as I know. Does this affect anyone else?

There is a plugin called 'Advanced TinyMce' also installed on the site and I don't believe the admin theme is affecting it.

Comment: make an bug report on Advanced TinyMce support page. try to reproduce the problem with the plugin deactivated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a z-index to the dropdown menu:

```
/**
 * My own fix for this issue:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908664/cannot-leave-full-screen-on-tinymce-wordpress-view-fullscreen/46908665
 * @return string Admin CSS
 */
function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>
    [id^="mceu_"].mce-container.mce-panel.mce-floatpanel {
        z-index: 2323232323 !important;
    }
  </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');
```

Comment: please report this bug to the Advanced TinyMCE developers on their plugin page...

Comment: but you discover what was the cause of the problem? (I mean not what happened but why it happened)

Comment: No I'm too busy fixing other stuff unfortunately. I don't have all day to investigate. This is a fix however.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of the fixed position of the fullscreen class.

```
div.mce-fullscreen {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

in skin.min.css,
other options don't give you a fullscreen page though